# right syntax to update mysql highest id

Tags: mysql

this is how i select highest id for a specific username

```
SELECT * FROM  messages WHERE user='me' ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 0, 1
```

i have column named "send" and a user named me

now i want to update it like this :

```
UPDATE   messages SET `send`='ok' WHERE user='me' ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 0, 1
```

i get syntax error

## 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ' 1' at line 1

Comment: Maybe thats because of the ` send `? Besides, i think you can simply do WHERE user='me' AND id = max (id)

Comment: What about `select max(id) from messages`?

Comment: the select one works but when i try to update it ,it gives me error

Comment: @xcoder i tried this UPDATE   messages SET send='ok' WHERE user='me' AND id = max(id) it gives me error  #1111 - Invalid use of group function

Comment: UPDATE messages SET send='ok' WHERE user='me' AND id = (select max(id) from messages)

Comment: Just remove the offset - (I can't believe you didn't think to try this)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `limit` in `update` only allows a row count, not an offset:

```
UPDATE messages
    SET `send`='ok'
    WHERE user='me'
    ORDER BY id DESC
    LIMIT 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

I feel like you're setting yourself up for failure here.

If you're going to select the highest ID before updating, then:

```
SELECT max(id) FROM  messages WHERE user='me'
```

Your UPDATE should be using that same ID you just retrieved as the WHERE clause. Otherwise, you can potentially update the wrong row with "ok". Full code, as I would do it:

```
// Get ID to update
$idToUpdate_q = $pdoConn->prepare("SELECT max(messages.id) FROM  messages WHERE user = :user");
$idToUpdate_q->bindValue(':user','me');
$idToUpdate_q->execute();
$idToUpdate = $idToUpdate_q->fetchColumn();

// Update Row
$updateRow_sql = $pdoConn->prepare("UPDATE messages
SET
messages.send = :send
WHERE
messages.id = :idToUpdate");

$updateRow_sql->execute(array(
':send' =>'ok',
':idToUpdate' =>$idToUpdate));
```

Comment: thanks ,thats what im doin actually basically i have a table that has id,name,question,send, the user insert into the table ,name,question, and me the admin i update send as the answer of the user question,and if the user ask too many questions,which means many id,i just update the answer of last id of their question,which works fine now